# Mapbox: setHTML() in Popup?

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I'm trying to use setHTML in popUp window to do the following:

The "name" text becomes a hyperlink to another page.

Here is the code to the project without setHTML():

```
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2l5dWNjaGVuIiwiYSI6ImNsYnZoYjViZzJoNXozcHBqbzR1Y2pxZjQifQ.5H9fghwphrlDGMgs2bgnqQ';

const bounds = [
[120.993700, 30.669902], // Southwest coordinates
[122.209481, 31.828037] // Northeast coordinates
];  

const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map', // container ID
// Choose from Mapbox's core styles, or make your own style with Mapbox Studio
style: 'mapbox://styles/siyucchen/clbwfvq7t000815rw928y0oak', // style URL
center: [121.487, 31.2239], // starting position [lng, lat]
maxZoom: 18,
minZoom: 14.9,
maxBounds: bounds
});



const list = [
  {
    name: 'Intersection between Beikongjia Alley and Jinjiafang Road',
    color: '#cf302d',
    lngLat: [121.480965,31.223564],
  },
  {
    name: 'Interior of No.91, Jinjiafang Road',
    color: '#cf302d',
    lngLat: [121.48199,31.22394]
  }                 
]

list.forEach(({name, color, lngLat}) => {
const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }).setText(name)

  new mapboxgl.Marker({
    color,
    scale: 0.6
  })  
  
  .setLngLat(lngLat)
  .setPopup(popup)
  .addTo(map);
})


  map.on('load', () => {
    map.setFog({});
    })

    map.scrollZoom.enable({around: 'center'});

});
```

I saw this example on Mapbox (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/popup-on-click/) and tried the following, but doesn't work:

```
const list = [
  {
    name: 'Intersection between Beikongjia Alley and Jinjiafang Road',
    color: '#cf302d',
    description: '`<p><a href="link1.html">CLICK FOR MORE INFO</p>`',
    lngLat: [121.480965,31.223564],
  },
  {
    name: 'Interior of No.91, Jinjiafang Road',
    color: '#cf302d',
    description: '`<p><a href="link2.html">CLICK FOR MORE INFO</p>`',
    lngLat: [121.48199,31.22394]
  }                 
]

list.forEach(({name, color, descriptionlngLat}) => {
const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }).setText(name)

  new mapboxgl.Marker({
    color,
    scale: 0.6
  })  
  
  .setLngLat(lngLat)
  .setHTML(description)
  .setPopup(popup)
  .addTo(map);
})
```

Helps will be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to set color option, your code is working :

```js
mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1Ijoic2l5dWNjaGVuIiwiYSI6ImNsYnZoYjViZzJoNXozcHBqbzR1Y2pxZjQifQ.5H9fghwphrlDGMgs2bgnqQ';

const bounds = [
[120.993700, 30.669902], // Southwest coordinates
[122.209481, 31.828037] // Northeast coordinates
];  

const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
container: 'map', // container ID
// Choose from Mapbox's core styles, or make your own style with Mapbox Studio
style: 'mapbox://styles/siyucchen/clbwfvq7t000815rw928y0oak', // style URL
center: [121.487, 31.2239], // starting position [lng, lat]
maxZoom: 18,
minZoom: 14.9,
maxBounds: bounds
});



const list = [
  {
    name: 'Intersection between Beikongjia Alley and Jinjiafang Road',
    color: '#cf302d',
    lngLat: [121.480965,31.223564],
  },
  {
    name: 'Interior of No.91, Jinjiafang Road',
    color: '#cf302d',
    lngLat: [121.48199,31.22394]
  }                 
];

list.forEach(({name, color, lngLat}) => {
const popup = new mapboxgl.Popup({ offset: 25 }).setText(name)
 
  new mapboxgl.Marker({
    color : color,
    scale: 0.6
  })  
  
  .setLngLat(lngLat)
  .setPopup(popup)
  .addTo(map);
})


  map.on('load', () => {
    map.setFog({});
    });

   map.scrollZoom.enable({around: 'center'});
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
<link href="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.11.0/mapbox-gl.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v2.11.0/mapbox-gl.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<di id="map"></di>
</body>
</html>
```